# Can the session[:id] ever be blank?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm in the process of integrating Segment.io into my app. Their docs have suggested passing the session id for anonymous event tracking. I'd like to implement this when a user first visits the landing page.

However, I'm curios if the session id can ever be blank?

```
request.session_options[:id]
```

Comment: Well, it depends on your app. Do you force the authentication before establishing the connection between your serveur Socket and the client? -> IF Yes THEN session[:id] should never be nil ELSE it could be nil for non-authenticated user.

Comment: Unless rails forces the connection out of the box, then my answer is no. I need to retrieve the session id at the initial visit, which is a non-authenticated user. What would cause the session id to never be set?

Comment: When you don't set it? I mean usually User authentication leads to set a `session[:user_id]` value. If the user, at his initial visit, is not authenticating, he will not have a value in `session[:id]` (unless you set it, like a random uniq key generated).

Comment: I seem to have misunderstood the session id. I thought the session id would be present on any server call.

Comment: Try in your app, in a controller: `raiser session[:id]` => can be nil (is nil in my case, but `session[:user_id]` is not)

Comment: Oh, my bad: `raiser request.session_options[:id]` proves that the session id exists. But calling `session[:id]` is not the same as `request.session_options[:id]`. (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_ID)

Comment: Interesting. I'm using `request.session_options[:id]` for now. But I'll make sure it exists before I do anything with it.